# Problemas con mis triggers en Mysql: General error: 1093

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

**Tengo Mysql 8 y trate de agregar unos triggers a una tabla, pero tengo el siguiente error:**

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table
> 'venta' for update in FROM clause".

**Estas son mis tablas:**

**--> Venta.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**--> DetalleVenta.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*** Y este es mi trigger:***

```
BEGIN

UPDATE venta 
SET total_venta = (SELECT sum(precio_venta * cantidad) 
                   FROM detalle_venta 
                   WHERE venta_id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
                                     FROM venta)) 
WHERE total_venta = (SELECT total_venta FROM venta WHERE id = new.venta_id) OR total_venta IS NULL;

END
```

Comment: De principio, no deberías almacenar cálculos.

Answer (score 1):

En MySql no puedes hacer un UPDATE sobre una tabla y usar la misma tabla en una cláusula FROM. Está documentado [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) y también como se podría resolver.

Pero en tu caso me parece que podrías simplificar la query del trigger, si lo que quieres hacer es actualizar el total de la venta en función del precio de venta y la cantidad indicada en cada uno de sus renglones, lo podrías hacer de esta forma:

```
UPDATE venta 
SET total_venta = (SELECT sum(precio_venta * cantidad) 
                   FROM detalle_venta 
                   WHERE venta_id = new.venta_id) 
WHERE id = new.venta_id;
```

Si este trigger lo disparas al insertar o actualizar registros en detalle_venta, entonces deberías ejecutar el mismo después del insert o update de tal manera que ya estén el precio de venta y la cantidad actualizada, y de esta manera el total de la venta sea correcto.